# Import data with Sqoop, timestamp datatype

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

Is it possible to import data via Sqoop to a Hive table, stored as Parquet, and previously created with decimal and timestamp datatypes?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can import via to Sqoop to Hive table stored as Parquet.

[Sqoop has added Parquet Support](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-1366)

```
sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:mysql://the_mysql_server/the_mysql_database \
--username the_mysql_user --password the_mysql_password \
--table sourcetablename\
--hive-import –hive-table destinationtablename\
--as-parquetfile -m 1
```

If you want to change datatype to hive datatype while importing data from RDBMS

e.g

use this parameter `--map-column-hive col1=hivedatatype,col2=hivedatatype`

```
sqoop import \
...
...
--map-column-hive id=STRING,price=DECIMAL
```